# Is it normal size for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I just import my **Mysql** database (size 2,8 Mio) in my new **Mongo** database with very simple php script i build, import was ok without error but when i look my **Mongo** database (with RockMongo) i can see this : Data Size 8.01m, Storage Size 13.7m.

**MongoDB** is bigger than **Mysql** for the same amount of data, is this normal ?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's normal that the "same" data will take up more space in mongodb. There's a few things you need to take into account:

1) the document _id that's stored for each document (unless you are specifying your own value for that) is 12 bytes per doc
2) you're storing the key for each key-value pair in each document, whereas in MySql the column name is not stored for every single row so you have that extra overhead in your mongodb documents too. One way to reduce this is to use shortened key names ("column names") in your docs
3) mongodb automatically adds padding to allow documents to grow

In similar tests, loading data from SQL Server to MongoDB, with shortened 2 character document key names instead of the full names as per SQL Server, I see about 25-30% extra space being used in MongoDB.

Comment: Oh ok, i thinked already about the "1" (_id) but not about the "2", happy to ear that everything is fine, thank you very much :)

Comment: Regarding 3), this is also the case for relational databases. In Oracle you have PCTFREE and PCTUSED parameters controlling it. I guess MySQL does it also. On the other hand it should be noted, that data in MongoDB is compressed by default.